# Can't get the default controller of codeigniter to work in IIS

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, web-config

I am trying to host a codeigniter project on IIS Server but I can't get even the default controller to show instead what I receive is this below

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Creation of dynamic property CI_URI::$config is deprecated

Filename: core/URI.php

Line Number: 101

Backtrace:

File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I have web.config file, HTTP mappings, ISAPI, URL rewrite module and FastCGI all set but still the problem persist.
I will be very grateful if you guys can help me, am stranded.

Comment: https://forum.codeigniter.com/index.php will be a better place for such discussions. Since the error you got was caused by incompatibility with PHP 8.2, the original developers are the best resources to guide you.

Comment: CodeIgniter 3 is built to work with PHP 5.6 or newer, so it should be compatible with any version of PHP that is newer than PHP 5.6, including PHP 8.2.0.

Comment: You’d better make no such assumptions, as PHP changed so much and you observed this issue. If you search about that Message part, you can see tons of other similar issues.

Comment: @LexLi I downgraded my php version and now the problem is sovled.

Comment: According to your error message, it is a dynamic attribute that is deprecated as the PHP version is updated. A higher version of PHP does not necessarily have better compatibility.

Comment: It’s not resolved at all. 8.2 will become the minimal in just two years as any older releases will go end of life. So, treat this error seriously, instead of trying to hide.